# How to set a app run in background in iphone?

Tags: iphone, background

How to set a app run in background in iphone??

Answer (score 1):

refer a following code.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    //Create a task object
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;

    backgroundTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [app endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {

                // do stuff              

                [app endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform tasks for a limited time after your application is directed to go to the background, but only for the duration provided. Running for longer than this will cause your application to be terminated. See the "[Completing a Long-Running Task in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6)" section of the iOS Application Programming Guide for how to go about this.